# Почему при создании массива выдаёт Int32[] Array

Tags: c#, массивы, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при создании массива выдаёт Int32[] Array, а не полноценный текст из цифр?
[image: результат отображения]

```
<Window x:Class="_14._04._19.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:_14._04._19.ViewModel"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_14._04._19"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="250">
<Window.DataContext>
    <mvvm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding AllClassModel}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArrayInt}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</Grid>
```

```
  public class ClassModel : OnProperyChangedClass
{

    int[] arrayInt = { 10, 20, 20 };

    public int[] ArrayInt
    {
        get
        {
            return arrayInt;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: А что вы ожидали? Напишите где нибудь `string result = ArrayInt.ToString();`, что получите в `result`?

Comment: Будет пусто....

Comment: Вы привязываетесь к классу, его текстбоксу нужно как-то отобразить..., на классе вызывается метод `ToString()` и это всё. Он же не может прочитать ваши мысли и определить, что он привязан к массиву, и программист хочет от него, чтоб он пробежался по массиву и вывел через запятую его элементы ;) Как-то так.

Comment: Не могу я понять хоть убей, что неправильно делаю!!!!!!!!

Comment: Вот это `Text="{Binding ArrayInt}"`

Comment: при создании то массива всё верно; потому, что привязка `{Binding ...}` не умеет преобразовывать массив чисел в строку текста, нужно это реализовать самостоятельно в C# коде

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходима создать перегрузку метода `ToString()` для вашего класса, если конечно вы не хотите в классе содержать еще чего, что-бы потом выводить строку.

```
 public class ClassModel : OnProperyChangedClass
 {

     int[] arrayInt = { 10, 20, 20 };

    public int[] ArrayInt
    {
      get
      {
        return arrayInt;
      }
   }

  public override string ToString()
  {
      var res ="";
      foreach(var c in arrayInt)
      {
         res+=$"{c} ";//здесь вы можете установить нужный формат вывода
      }
      return res;
  }

 }
```

Если вам необходимо использовать метод `ToString()` для других целей, то целесообразно создать метод `IntArrToString()`:

```
  public string IntArrToString()
  {
      var res ="";
      foreach(var c in arrayInt)
      {
         res+=$"{c} ";//здесь вы можете установить нужный формат вывода
      }
      return res;
  }
```

Соответственно в коде использовать: `Text="{Binding ToString()}"` либо `Text="{Binding IntArrToString()}"`
Если не проходит как метод, попробуйте использовать как свойство:

```
 public string IntArrToString
  {
    get
    {
      var res ="";
      foreach(var c in arrayInt)
      {
         res+=$"{c} ";//здесь вы можете установить нужный формат вывода
      }
      return res;
    }
  }
```

соответственно в привязке использовать так:`Text="{Binding IntArrToString}"`

Comment: вы эту привязку проверяли? :) у меня почему-то не получается привязаться на метод, просто ничего не возвращает и даже в метод не заходит.

Comment: Честно не проверял, если так не проходит попробуйте использовать вместо метода свойство.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за подсказку, как только до компа доберусь, проэспериментирую ваш вариант.

Answer (score 0):

*полноценный текст из цифр*

```
public string ArrayInt
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Concat(  arrayInt.Select<int, string>(i => (i.ToString()))  );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ваш код аналогичен этому: `String.Concat(arrayInt)`. И хорошо бы добавить разделитель: `string.Join(" ", arrayInt)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вы убиваете интригу ;) касательно разделителей решительно протестую -- топикстартер хотел именно _полноценный текст из цифр_ !

Comment: _топикстартер хотел_ - Они сами не знают, чего они хочут (c) (Фраза из фильма)